# Is the SD card write protection hard-wired or optional?

Tags: hardware, integrity, storage, flash-memory

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#Card_security), the SD card reader recognizes if the little tab on the left of the SD card is in the "lock" position or not. Thus, a SD card reader *can* still write on the SD card even if the write protection is on by ignoring it.

Is it true that the write protection is only a voluntary feature by the card reader or is it a "switch" that securely turns write access off?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wikipedia is correct: **on SD cards, you have to trust the host system (whatever the card is plugged in to) to honor the physical write protect switch**. Here is the relevant text from the [publicly available specification documents](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/pls/simplified_specs/). Emphasis is mine.

> SD Specifications Part 1
>
> Physical Layer
>
> Simplified Specification
>
> Version 4.10 January 22, 2013
>
> 4.3.6 Write Protect Management
>
> Three write protect methods are supported in the SD Memory Card as follows:
>
> - Mechanical write protect switch (Host responsibility only)
> - Card internal write protect (Card's responsibility)
> - Password protection card lock operation.
>
> Mechanical Write Protect Switch
>
> A mechanical sliding tablet on the
> side of the card (refer to the Part 1 Standard Size SD Card Mechanical
> Addendum) will be used by the user to indicate that a given card is
> write protected or not. If the sliding tablet is positioned in such a
> way that the window is open it means that the card is write protected.
> If the window is close the card is not write-protected. A proper,
> matched, switch on the socket side will indicate to the host that the
> card is write-protected or not. **It is the responsibility of the host
> to protect the card. The position of the write protect switch is
> unknown to the internal circuitry of the card**.

Comment: It appears that there is also some hard-wired protection available ("Card internal write protect"), but this is only described in the confidential full specification and I think it is not linked to the write protect switch.